# ASP.NET MVC - Multiple views with same name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This question is mostly related to my previous question. I'm having an Edit view for my Product site to list the products with edit/delete link attached.. But how can I do:

/products/edit = show list with edit/delete links.

/products/edit/{productId} = show edit model (textboxes etc) for the specific product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always do this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? productId)
{
    if (productId != null)
    {
        return View("ViewWithTextBoxes.aspx");
    }
    return View("ViewWithEditDeleteLinks.aspx");
}
```

This being said, the case of showing edit and delete links doesn't seem like editing so I would recommend you using different action names. It seems more RESTful to me like this:

```
/products/index
/products/edit/{productId}
```

In this case you are having different actions and views for each case:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var products = _repository.GetProducts();
    return View(products);
}

public ActionResult Edit(int productId)
{
    var product = _repository.GetProduct(productId);
    return View(product);
}
```

Comment: Indeed.. but I cant do it that way because /products/index = should display list of products without delete/edit links for the customer, and /products/edit = should display list of products with delete/edit links for the logged in admin.

Comment: I think that your design is wrong. `/products/index` should check whether the currently logged in user is admin and show the links respectively instead of having `/products/index` for normal users and `/products/edit` for admins.

Comment: Might be.. but I'm having a hard time to see how I can do /products/index and check whether the user is logged in and still keep all the management in a control panel.

Comment: Ah.. or I might just do as you say.. check for authentication at the Index controller and then render either IndexWithOutLoginor IndexWithLogin view?

Comment: Darin, sorry to bother you once again.. But how would I make it possible to both view the IndexWithOutLogin when I just visit the regular site while I'm logged in, but still render IndexWithLogin when I'm in the management panel? Like... http://something.com/products = show normal product page even if you are logged in. http://something.com/management/products (or something like that) shows the edit list for the product page when you're logged in.

Comment: I'm using the Role attribute in my Controller, combined with authenticateRequest in my global.asax to hold the roles for each user updated.

Comment: Instead of having separate views, you can check if the user is logged in (or in a role with the correct permissions), and then display the edit links only inf the currently authenticated user is entitled to see those links.